# SQL generated by Entity Framework is missing a join

Tags: performance, entity-framework, linq

We noticed this query has a high amount of reads:

```
var var1 = "535d1a11-1c2b-467a-3333-222aaa9b1fd4";
var var2 = 117;
var test = (from t1 in contextObj.Table1
    join t2 in contextObj.Table2
        on t1.Column2 equals t2.Column1
    join t3 in contextObj.Table3 on t2.Column2 equals t3.Column1
    where t3.Column1 == var1 && t2.Column3 == var2
                             && t2.Column2 == var1
    select t1).ToList();
```

This is because the SQL generated by Entity Framework is missing a join:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Column1] AS [Column1], 
    [Extent1].[Column2] AS [Column2], 
    [Extent1].[Column3] AS [Column3], 
    [Extent1].[Column4] AS [Column4], 
    [Extent1].[Column5] AS [Column5], 
    [Extent1].[Column6] AS [Column6]
    FROM  [dbo].[Table1] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table2] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Column2] = [Extent2].[Column1]
    WHERE ([Extent2].[Column2] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent2].[Column3] = @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent2].[Column2] = @p__linq__2)',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 int,@p__linq__2 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'535d5b16-1c2b-467a-9022-933ebf9b1fd4',@p__linq__1=117,@p__linq__2=N'535d5b16-1c2b-467a-9022-933ebf9b1fd4'
```

Database create script: https://gist.github.com/jbouwens/85e8840d799b8178ee30feb389fbc4ac

Why did EF not include this join/what can I do to prevent this in the future? Thanks!

Comment: What version of EF?

Comment: Using version 6.2.0

Comment: This is just a guess, but since you are not returning any of the columns from Table 3 and EF assumes it can eliminate the join because Table 2 already contains a column that can satisfy your t3.Column1 == var1 filter, it does so thinking the performance would be better by not unnecessarily joining to Table 3.   Couple of things to try I guess....1)  add an index on Table2.Column2      2)  Return any column from Table3 to see if it does in fact do the join.

Comment: Didn't think about it in the first post, but a third option would be to remove the t2.Column2 == var1 filter from the query....this is what I would try first if it were me.

Comment: Including Table3 in my select seems to correct the issue, now the second join is included in generated SQL.

Comment: Cool...guess that somewhat validates what I was thinking...but...you shouldn't have to arbitrarily return columns just to get the join to work properly.   I would remove that return value and remove the T2.Column2 filter and see if you get the same results....I bet EF will then assume it has to join to Table3 no matter what and you dont pay the penalty of returning columns for nothing.

Comment: Would it matter if you apply filters before the join? Like so:
`join t2 in contextObj.Table2.Where(q => q.Column3 == var2 && q.Column2 == var1) on ..`
and 
`join t3 in contextObj.Table3.Where(q => q.Column1 == var1) on ..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query, the where clause is comparing t3.Column1 == var1 and t2.Column2 == var1, but since your join already takes into account that t3.Column1 == t2.Column2, EF is automagically removing what it assumes is non-needed join.  Since the table structure is not ideal, the solution has been determined to return a column from table3 to force EF into joining to the table.

```
var test = (from t1 in contextObj.Table1new 
    join t2 in contextObj.Table2
        on t1.Column2 equals t2.Column1
    join t3 in contextObj.Table3 on t2.Column2 equals t3.Column1
    where t3.Column1 == var1 && t2.Column3 == var2
    select new { t1, t3.Column1 }).ToList()
```

Comment: I see what you mean. However, that join is still missing after removing && t2.Column2 == var1

Comment: Interesting....not what I would have expected....let me try to reproduce and see what I can come up with.

Comment: After running your script, I think you have a bigger issue than just the query.   All of this is hard to understand since your example is just random names and columns that have little meaning, but I will try to explain what I see.  Table3 has a 1:M relationship with Table1 and Table 2 has a 1:M relationship with Table1.  This by definition means there is a M:M relationship between Table 3 and Table 2.   This is fine.   The issue comes with the 1:M relationship between Table3 and Table2.   This is not a good design.  Let's put some context to your table names so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Let's call Table3 "Order".  And Table2 "Item".  And Table 1 "OrderItem"...ie...the items that belong to any given order.  By adding the 1:M relationship between Order and Item directly, the model is effectively saying that an item belongs to an order, but your intersection table (Table1) states that isn't true and that an item can belong to many orders.  Now, this doesn't directly answer your original question about the join, but it does show a much bigger problem with your schema than just this query represents.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, I think you should think through your table's structures and not just try to "fix" this query.

Comment: Sorry about the naming. I deliberately obfuscated it as this isn’t technically my code. It would have been better to give them meaningful names. Thanks for all the info, I’ll let you know if I have any additional questions or feedback.

Comment: That being said, I do believe your first comment is the answer. With the caveat that this problem in the first place indicates deeper structural issues in the schema. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries...I obfuscate stuff all the time on SO for the same reason...completely understand the reasoning.   I'll update the answer to include returning t3 if you want to accept as an answer so it can be closed out.

Answer (score 1):

I repro'd this and EF is "trusting" your declared foreign keys in its query generation, which SQL Server will do too (if you have them enforced and checked).

EF is transforming the predicate `t3.Column1 == var1` to `[Extent2].[Column3] = @p__linq__1` since you joined those columns in the query, and the Foreign Key guarantees that the join will change the rowcount.